# Django creating update post function

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a post update/edit function but I have a problem. When I click "Update" button there is no error but there is no change. I think reason of that a mistake that I made in models.py but I can not figure it out. And here is my code

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
          .
          .
          .
    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('post:post_update', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**views.py**

```
def post_update(request, slug):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():

        return Http404()

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "Updated")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, "blog/post_update.html", context)
```

**post_update.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block body %}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Form</h1>
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    {{ form.media }}
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create post">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

**post_detail.html**

//update link

```
  <p ><a href="?P<slug>[\w-]+)/update/">update</a></p>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/update/$', post_update, name="update"),
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text',)
```

Where is my mistake? What can I do?

Comment: Add the related URLs please

Comment: Add also your PostForm definition

Comment: Okey, I did it now

Comment: I think you meant to use get_absolute_url instead of get_update_url in models.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url